# Blender 2.78a (When im trying to move my object and enter a value it doesn't work)

Tags: blender

I'm having problem with my work in blender, im using the latest version of the blende 2.78a.

But when i try to move my object and hit the x key then enter a value (2.50) it doesn't work.

Any help please =)

Answer (score 0):

Did you first selected the object with right mousbutton and pressed the G key for moving the object?

If it still not works I have some other suggestions for you:

1. select the model, go to the panel on the right, press the "Object data" button (with the orange Cube on it) and then enter the numbers at "Location"
2. make sure you enter the numbers with a . not a , !!! (i also made this mistake)
3. press N to open an new propertiespanel on the right of the 3d-view and
   look at the "Location"s; are the locks behind the coordinates blocked?
   if so just click to unlock the positions

Comment: Ty sir for your response.